# Blank Button in Jquery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to make a popup dialog form with jQuery UI, but the buttons that are generated do not have any text in them.

```
$(function(){
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                alert("test");
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
```

The code of the generated button is this:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
 <button type="button" text="OK" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
   <span class="ui-button-text"/>
 </button>
</div>
```

Also, the code of the button handler is executed when the page loads, which means I see the "test" popup when i load the page

I'm using jQuery and jQuery UI loaded by the Google API

Comment: Can you prove this at http://jsfiddle.net with your code? Works find for me http://jsfiddle.net/N9emj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me! I was using an older version of jQuery (1.3.2) which should be fully compatible with jQuery UI, but I guess not. Thanks!